# Correct pattern for Android app using fragments

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm currently developing a simple Android app which is basically a list of items which when clicked display a second screen with details.

Here's the app hierarchy:

```
---> MainActivity.java
   --> MyListFragment.java
   --> MyDetailFragment.java
```

So when the app is opened, the list is displayed via the MyListFragment.java and when an item is clicked, the item position is passed into MyDetailFragment.java and the fragment is replaced to display the detail of that item.

Currently I tried to implement an up caret button when MyDetailFragment.java is loaded but ended up with bugs such as the up caret appearing when MyListFragment.java is also loaded back when the user presses 'back' or uses the up caret button.

After researching the problem online, I see that some users use separate activities along with fragments which look like the following:

```
---> MainListActivity.java
  --> MyListFragment.java
---> DetailListActivity.java
  --> MyDetailFragment.java
```

My question: Which pattern is better to use, the first or the second and why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: why fragments at all?  why not MainListActivity.java -> DetailListActivity.java? where do you guys read that every app has to use fragments?

Comment: I tend to put as little logic as possible in Activity and all relevant options for actionbar etc. in the fragments. This way, only when the fragment is added for MyDetailFragment, the up caret is shown. Could you share how you currently implemented the up navigation?

Comment: Fragments will allow flexibility in arranging layout for tablets as well.

@cYrixmorten, I've added getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); and setHasOptionsMenu(true); to the onCreateView method of the Fragment.

Comment: And added onCreateOptionsMenu inside the fragment, showing the options relevant for the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment  maybe you have to add the fragment using a tag, say "ListFragment", and in the Activity check if the fragment is visible:

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragment"); 
if (fragment != null && fragment.isAdded() && fragment.isVisible()) {
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
} else {
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); 
}
```

This could be done in onResume or onCreateOptionsMenu of the Activity.

Using setHasOptionsMenu(true) for fragments allow fragments to add more options menu items that belongs to the fragment. But since you are calling:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I believe that setHasOptionsMenu(true) has no effect in this scenario as you are talking directly to the Activity. This is also why removing the fragment does not change/remove the up caret.

Another possible solution could be to manually remove the up caret whenever the fragment is detatched.

```
public void onDetach () {
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // <- not sure if needed
}
```

**Ok, so now I have looked over your code. Here is my suggestion:**

Note that I have not tested this code and is written in notepad, so might contain some typos.

**MainActivity:**
Move the up caret responsibility to the Activity (setOptionsMenu(true) for fragments is not meant to handle this anyway).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "hisnul.sqlite3";

    //A good practice is to define database field names as constants
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "en_dua";
    private static final String DUA_ID = "_id";
    private static final String DUA_TITLE = "title";

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ArrayList duas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new FragmentDuaList())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_dualist, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }

    private void restoreActionBar() {
        Fragment detailFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DetailListFragment");
        if (detailFragment != null) {
            // means a detail fragment has been added and we need the up caret
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } else {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        // why not use switch case here?
        if(id == android.R.id.home) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Test Caret", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                Log.d("Khalid", "Testing CARET");
                return true;
        } if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_bookmarks){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Favorites Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dua_list, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentDuaList:** 
No changes here

**FragmentDuaDetail:**
Remove the ActionBar code:

```
public class FragmentDuaDetail extends Fragment {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "hisnul.sqlite3";

    //A good practice is to define database field names as constants
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "en_dua";
    private static final String DUA_ID = "_id";
    private static final String DUA_TITLE = "title";

    private static final String DUA_ARABIC = "arabic";
    private static final String DUA_TRANSLATION = "translation";
    private static final String DUA_REFERENCE = "reference";

    private String title;
    private String arabic;
    private String translation;
    private String reference;

    private String dua_from_list_fragment;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ArrayList duaDetails;

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dua_detail, container, false);

        dua_from_list_fragment = getArguments().getString("dua_id");

        //Our key helper
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(getActivity(), DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        //That’s it, the database is open!
        fillDua();
        setUpDuaList();

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void fillDua(){
        //Extracting Elements from Database
        duaDetails = new ArrayList<DuaDetail>();
        Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DUA_TITLE,
                DUA_ARABIC, DUA_TRANSLATION, DUA_REFERENCE}, DUA_ID + "=" + dua_from_list_fragment, null, null, null, null);
        friendCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                title = friendCursor.getString(0);
                arabic = friendCursor.getString(1);
                translation = friendCursor.getString(2);
                reference = friendCursor.getString(3);
                duaDetails.add(new DuaDetail(title, arabic, translation, reference));
            } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        friendCursor.close();
    }

    public void setUpDuaList(){
        TextView tvDuaTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuaTitle);
        TextView tvDuaArabic = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuaArabic);
        TextView tvDuaTranslation = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuaTranslation);
        TextView tvDuaReference = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuaReference);

        Typeface face;
        face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf");
        tvDuaArabic.setTypeface(face);

        tvDuaTitle.setText(title);
        tvDuaArabic.setText(arabic);
        tvDuaTranslation.setText(translation);
        tvDuaReference.setText(reference);
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can't seem to get this. Could you take a glance at my code at GitHub? : https://github.com/khalid-hussain/HisnulMuslim

Comment: I tried the code but now I don't have any caret and the logo and app name are not clickable. I tested the code on an emulator. Thank you for the effort so far.

Comment: Maybe `onCreateOptionsMenu` of the Activity is not called when adding fragments. Was not sure about that to be honest. Try adding `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` to FragmentDuaDetail to make the Activity invoke `onCreateOptionsMenu` and update the actionbar. Added it to the code in the answer.

Comment: The caret is back, which is great. Unfortunately we're back to square one. It still stays there when I return to the main list.